# Unable to run solana Hello World program in WSL

Tags: solana-cli, solana-test-validator

I have been following `Josh's DevBox` video to get started with `Solana`. In WSL environment, I did all the process, but at the end while executing `npm run start`, it comes up with `Segmentation Fault`.

[image: Error]

Any kind of assistance will be appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Its not a solana error rather a WSL error.Try downgrading your WSL version.You can follow [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75753668/wsl-2-vs-code-segmentation-fault) thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Solana error. Your installation of WSL, solana, rust should be matched with the versions required, else you will keep receiving the error.
https://docs.solana.com/getstarted/hello-world